# Saving text file in db and retrieving

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to store a text file in the form of byte array and has to read it back from the database and need to write on text file. What can i Do? I am using sql server 2008 R2 and vb.net

Answer (score 0):

The could use varbinary(max) for the data type in sql. If saving space change max to a smaller number better noted here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the text file to `byte[]` and store it in column of `image` datatype. When you retrieve this data from data base you will need to type cast to `byte[]` and using `FileStream` you can convert it into the file.

Following are some helpful links

- http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/01/how-to-insert-images-into-database-and.html
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/42cec0cb-5761-4aaa-93dc-861b29ee5ea6

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for the answer... I hv stored the text in the varbinary(max). But not able to convert it to text while retrieving.... pls help...

Comment: How are you saving the data in sql, please post the code? Also go through this [Converting varbinary(max) to byte array](http://forums.asp.net/p/1494040/3519438.aspx). Secondly you didn't mention anything about storing data in `varbinary(max)`. Give all the details related to your question.